# Applying a CSS transition when adding a class via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am creating the a button, that when clicked, will reveal an email input for the user to fill out. This is working, I just want a smooth transition so the action is not "jerky".

This is the HTML for the button and form

```
<button id="work" onclick="workyes()">Sign Up!</button>
<div id="workyes" class="invisible">
    <form><input type='email'></form>
</div>
```

The CSS I'm Using:

```
button {
border: 0;
background: #5786c1;
color: white;
padding: 8px 14px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block; /* needed for anchors */
position: relative;
box-shadow: 1px 0px #3a587f, 0px 1px #4171ae,
          2px 1px #3a587f, 1px 2px #4171ae,
          3px 2px #3a587f, 2px 3px #4171ae,
          4px 3px #3a587f, 3px 4px #4171ae,
          5px 4px #3a587f, 4px 5px #4171ae,
          6px 5px #3a587f, 5px 6px #4171ae;
           -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
           transition: all 1s;
           max-height: inherit;

}
button:hover {
box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
transition: all 1s; 
}
.invisible {
display: none;
}
.visible {
display: block;
}
```

And the JS that ties it all together:

```
function workyes() {
var box = $('#work');
var form = $('#workyes');
box.toggleClass('invisible');
form.toggleClass('visible');
}
```

I have an on hover transition that works but I just can't get one to work when the `.invisible` or `.visible` classes are added to the script.

Is there any way to make the CSS transitions work or add an effect in a different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add a second argument to the `toggleClass();` function that specifies duration to smooth out the transition:

```
function workyes() {
  var box = $('#work');
  var form = $('#workyes');
  box.toggleClass('invisible', 1000);
  form.toggleClass('visible', 500);
}
```

Alternatively you can use the `fadeToggle();`, `slideToggle();` or `fadeIn();` / `fadeOut();` functions.

Note - you should probably use jQuery's click function rather than the onclick html attribute.

HTML

```
<button id="clickToShowForm">Sign Up!</button>
<div class="hidden">
    <form><input type='email'></form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('clickToShowForm').click(function(){
  $('hidden').fadeToggle();
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding a duration to the toggle effect did not help. However, when I used `slideToggle` or `fadeOut` I had better results. The only standing problem I have is that the button when given any of these effects just lightens in color, then vanishes. The email input does work; so that's good. Is there any way you could help with the button not working properly?

Comment: Try fadeToggle too :) ...and I'm not sure what you mean about the button - can you create a separate question for that issue and post the link here?

Comment: I ended up using the `.animate` function and creating something along the lines of `box.animate({opacity: '0'});`, and that worked fine. Does the same thing as `.fadeOut`. Must be a bug. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use the fadeIn and fadeOut functions from jquery, and when the animation is finished, add/remove the class? (Although not really necessary anymore..)

```
<button id="work">Sign Up!</button>
<div id="workyes" class="invisible">
   <form id="workyes">
      <input type='email'>
   </form>
</div>
```

you better use the jquery selectors instead of an 'onclick' event on the element itself.

```
$("#work").click(function () {
   $(this).fadeToggle("slow", function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('invisible'); 
      $('#workyes').fadeToggle("slow", function () {
         $('#workyes').toggleClass('visible').focus(); 
      });
   });
});
```

I would think the toggleClass lines are not necessary anymore? Maybe you use there classes for other reasons.. so i left them in...

Take a look here for demo : https://jsfiddle.net/bff1y83b/